# MariaDB convert created_at timestamp in total hours from now

Tags: sql, database, timestamp, mariadb

I have following question which return `created_at` timestamps. I would like to convert it in total hours from now. Is there an easy way to make that conversion and print it in total hours?

MariaDB version `10.5.12-MariaDB-1:10.5.12+maria~focal-log`

```
MariaDB [nova]> select hostname, uuid, instances.created_at, instances.deleted_at, json_extract(flavor, '$.cur.*."name"') AS FLAVOR from instances join instance_extra on instances.uuid = instance_extra.instance_uuid WHERE (vm_state='active' OR vm_state='stopped');
+----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| hostname | uuid                                 | created_at          | deleted_at | FLAVOR       |
+----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| vm1      | ef6380b4-5455-48f8-9e4b-3d04199be3f5 | 2023-01-05 14:25:51 | NULL       | ["tempest2"] |
+----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Use the [`timestampdiff()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestampdiff/) function. It allows you to specify the units, so use `HOUR` as the unit.

Comment: something like this `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,instances.created_at)` ? i tried but didn't work.

Comment: It needs two timestamp arguments, to get the difference between them. Use `NOW()` as the current time.

Comment: I edited your question and tags to indicate you are using MariaDB. MariaDB and MySQL are different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed significantly since then. We should not think of them as the same or compatible products anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT hostname, UUID, instances.created_at, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,instances.created_at, NOW()) AS HOURDIFF,
       instances.deleted_at, 
       JSON_EXTRACT(flavor, '$.cur.*."name"') AS FLAVOR 
FROM instances 
JOIN instance_extra ON instances.uuid = instance_extra.instance_uuid 
WHERE (vm_state='active' OR vm_state='stopped');
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p4iLbfef)

Comment: ideally you store created_at in UTC and use utc_timestamp(), not now().  now() will use the timezone of the session.  if created_at is a timestamp field, it will also be returned in the timezone of the session, so timestampdiff will be off when there is a daylight savings change between the stored time and now.  if created_at is a datetime field, there's the additional possibility that it may have been set to a time with a different timezone and be off some number of hours.

Comment: I'm not considering daylight savings since there's none where I live but I agree that it is important to those who have it. I think you should post an answer to address that @ysth.